# konsole loses its ability to copy

Tags: cinnamon, konsole, copy-and-paste

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.  My window manager is Cinammon 3.6.7.

I run konsole (version 15.12.3) as my terminal, because I like its features.  As far as I know, I don't have any KDE installed other than whatever is needed to make konsole work.

Occasionally, my konsole(s) will lose the ability to copy.  I'm not sure what causes this, but it does get fixed if I log out and log back in.  I'd like to find a way to fix the problem without doing so.  Right now, I just wanted to copy some konsole output into a file.

Interestingly, when I go to File->Save Output As, after choosing a file to output to, I get:

> A problem occurred when saving the output.
>
> Could not start process Cannot talk to klauncher: The name org.kde.klauncher5 was not provided by any .service files

I thought at first that this was a broader mouse clipboard issue.  Consequently, I installed parcellite to see what was happening.  When I copy from other windows (e.g. my Chrome browser), copy and paste work fine, and parcellite sees the buffers appropriately.  I can even paste into konsole.  I simply can't copy from it.

Is there anything I can do to get my copying to work that doesn't involve logging out or rebooting, or is this just an artifact that happens occasionally when running konsole without the rest of KDE?

An added complication - I don't have root access to this machine, and have to do a lot of convincing to get any sudo access added.  I do have the ability to sudo apt, so I can update packages, if appropriate.  If there's something glaringly wrong with the way konsole is installed, it would help if I can tell IT exactly what they need to fix.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, still has the same issue. Sometimes I lose all ability to copy. Sometimes I can only copy from chrome or slack. Now it's just konsole that I can't copy from - both on text selection and ctrl-c.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: The same here on Kubuntu 18.04: Konsole (and, consequently - guake and yakuake) lose ability to copy text from the scrollback buffer. At some very rare times the ability can come back without restarting anything, and, more typically, clipboard works in some Konsole windows (all tabs), but does not work in other Konsole windows (all tabs). wm=Plasma, with multiple desktops.